# How to bind a property to an specific position of an array in a MvxViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Suppose I have a MvxViewModel with a string array property:

```
using System;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
namespace Foo {
    public class FooViewModel : MvxViewModel {
        private string[] mTexts;
        public string[] Texts {
            get { return mTexts; }
            set {
                mTexts = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Texts);
            }
        }
        public void Init()
        {
            Texts = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose I also have an iOS MvxViewController with a single string property:

```
using System;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
namespace Foo {
    public class FooView : MvxViewController {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public override void ViewDidLoad () {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            var bindset = this.CreateBindingSet<FooView, FooViewModel>();
            bindset.Bind(Text).To("Texts[0]");
            bindset.Apply();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I bind this string property, `Text`, to one position (say, 0) of the `Texts` array?

I have found sources ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095020/how-to-bind-arrays-i-mvvmcross) and [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/110)) which indicate that this would be possible by what was done int the `ViewDidLoad()` method above, however, I get a warning: `Unable to bind: source property source not found IndexedProperty:0 on String[]`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want to bind to a static index in your array? What's the use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `List` or `ObservableCollection` instead of an `Array`:

```
private List<string> mTexts;
public List<string> Texts
{
    get { return mTexts; }
    set
    {
        mTexts = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Texts);
    }
}
```

---

I'm not to sure on [Mvx support for `Array` type properties](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/data-binding#section-swiss). I always tend to use an `ObservableCollection` or `List`. The error message you get when trying to bind to an `Array`seems to suggest it's struggling to do an index lookup on the `Array`.

> Unable to bind: source property source not found IndexedProperty:0 on String[]

One approach that I tried and seemed to work was to implement an `Indexer` in the ViewModel and then bind to that.

***ViewModel***

```
string[] mTexts;
public string this[int index] => mTexts[index];

public void Init()
{
    mTexts = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
}
```

***View Bindings***

```
var bindset = this.CreateBindingSet<FooView, FooViewModel>();
bindset.Bind(Text).To(".[1]");
bindset.Apply();
```

*As noted by xleon in the comments below, the period is optional. Using `"[1]"` will work as well.*

Alternative with Lambda:

```
var bindset = this.CreateBindingSet<FooView, FooViewModel>();
bindset.Bind(Text).To(vm => vm[1]);
bindset.Apply();
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Do you actually need the dot before [1]? I use a similar approach for translations: https://github.com/xleon/I18N-Portable#data-binding-and-mvvm-frameworks

Comment: @xleon, you are right it is optional, ["If $SourcePath$ is omitted or a single period "." is used, then the Source used is the whole of the ViewModel."](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/data-binding#section-swiss). Thinking of it now, writing it will a lambda would probably be even better and it conveys clearly that it is directly off the `ViewModel`, `bindset.Bind(Text).To(vm => vm[1]);`

Comment: @xleon, I quite like your translation library, looks like a very clean way to do translation, I will need to given it a try :)

Comment: Indeed, the use of arrays was what caused my code to fail; simply changed Texts from `string[]` to `List<string>` and the binding worked as desired. Thank you.